# Getting a URL from a JPG file in python

Tags: python, cloud, web-hosting, detection, face-detection

I'm making a program that does face detection.  When it detects an unknown face, it saves the frame and sends a text to a list of phone numbers.  The issue I'm facing is that I would like to attach the jpg file that is saved (of that frame) to the text.  However the way I'm sending the text it needs to be a url.  I haven't done much with cloud hosting which I think would be the easiest way to get a url for it.. what would be a good place to do that that's free?  Also, it does have to be a http/https url, I tried doing the local file url but it does actually have to be a web one.  Would cloud hosting it be the easy option, or would it be easier to just host a local html site that holds the image?  And how would I go about hosting it in python if that is the easier option?

I've looked for cloud hosting options, but I'm not really sure what to use that's free, and how to go about doing it from python.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that recommendation of services is not allowed on this site, but you do need to have it hosted online, because when you send an image it usualy doesn't send the actual file. It just tell the reciepiat where to look for the file, so both you and the reveiver need to have acces to the site. A way that I know could work is getting a firebase sub-domain, but that would probs be more work then needed, but it should be a solid solution if you aren't planning on sending over 10 of then a day or to have 50 people look at them.